# How to display coordinates under cursor in web map?

Tags: arcgis-server, c#, asp.net, arcgis-web-adf

I'd like to be able to display the X/Y coordinates of the user's current mouse cursor location such as with this [web map](http://maps.ocpafl.org/webmap/).

I'm using the .NET Web ADF, C# and ArcGIS Server.

Can anyone suggest any code samples for this?

Comment: Which web client/API are you using?

Comment: i'm using .net ADF

Comment: (-) At least read the docs on http://resources.arcgis.com/content/arcgissdks/10.0/net Please help yourself. Otherwise, why should we help you?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [Common Custom JavaScript sample](http://help.arcgis.com/en/sdk/10.0/serveradf_net/conceptualhelp/index.html#//000200000156000000) in the [Web ADF 10 SDK Help](http://help.arcgis.com/en/sdk/10.0/serveradf_net/adf_home.html) has an example of updating the browser status bar with the current mouse cursor coordinates. See `Default.aspx` for the JavaScript implementation.

In the `initialize()` function:

```
// Show map coordinates in status bar based on cursor location
map.add_mouseMove(mouseMove);
```

A bit further down:

```
// Show map coordinates in status bar associated with cursor location
function mouseMove(sender,eventArgs) {
    window.status = sender.get_id() + ': ' + 
      eventArgs.coordinate.get_x().toFixed(3) + ', ' + 
      eventArgs.coordinate.get_y().toFixed(3);
}
```